# JQuery UI Datepicker and Angular JS in custom Umbraco Dashboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, umbraco, jquery-ui-datepicker

I recently built a custom dashboard with the help of Sebastiaan forums in this post:

http://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/60887-Custom-dashboard-Umbraco-update-service

However, I have now modified my code in an attempt to make the interface more user friendly by including a datepicker on two fields so that our users can pass two dates into our web services and have a result returned.

The problem is, I am receiving the following Javascript errors in Firebug when I try and access my Dashboard in the back office:

> Error: Argument 'AxumUpdateService' is not a function, got undefined
>   cb@http://localhost:60282/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js:17:79
>   xa@http://localhost:60282/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js:17:187
>   Jc/this.$gethttp://localhost:60282/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js:53:310
>   k/<@http://localhost:60282/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js:44:274
>   n@http://localhost:60282/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js:7:72
>   k@http://localhost:60282/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js:44:139
>   e@http://localhost:60282/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js:40:139
>   y/<@http://localhost:60282/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js:39:205
>   Odhttp://localhost:60282/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js:158:14
>   u/j.success/<@http://localhost:60282/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js:100:347
>   Uc/e/j.promise.then/i@http://localhost:60282/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js:79:432
>   Uc/e/j.promise.then/i@http://localhost:60282/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js:79:432
>   Uc/e/j.promise.then/i@http://localhost:60282/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js:79:432
>   Uc/e/j.promise.then/i@http://localhost:60282/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js:79:432
>   Uc/g/<.then/<@http://localhost:60282/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js:80:485
>   Xc/this.$gethttp://localhost:60282/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js:92:268
>   Xc/this.$gethttp://localhost:60282/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js:90:140
>   Xc/this.$gethttp://localhost:60282/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js:92:429
>   j@http://localhost:60282/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js:101:78
>   r@http://localhost:60282/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js:104:449
>   dd/http://localhost:60282/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js:106:90
>
> http://localhost:60282/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js Line
>   63

At first I thought it was due to some of my Javascript causing a conflict but I have checked it and there are no missing semicolons or errors in the code.

I then checked my package.manifest to ensure that Jquery was called before AngularJS as this is advised on most forums however, this still hasn't helped with this issue.

Does anybody know how to circumvent these issues?

package.manifest

```
{
  javascript:[
    "~/app_plugins/Dashboards/jquery-1.11.2.min.js,
    "~/app_plugins/Dashboards/css/jquery-ui.min.js",
    "~/app_plugins/Dashboards/AxumUpdateServiceJquery.js",
    "~/app_plugins/Dashboards/AxumUpdateService.controller.js",
    "~/app_plugins/Dashboards/AxumUpdateService.service.js",
  ],
  css:[
    "~/app_plugins/Dashboards/css/axumupdateservice.min.css",
    "~/app_plugins/Dashboards/css/jquery-ui.min.css"
  ]
}
```

AxumUpdateService.service.js

```
angular.module("umbraco.services").factory("AxumUpdateService", function ($http) {
    return {
        getAll: function (from, to) {
            from = from || "";
            to = to || "";
            return $http.get("/umbraco/api/Axum/GetAllGroupTours" + "?fromDate=" + from + "&toDate=" + to);
        }
    }
});
```

AxumUpdateService.controller.js

```
angular.module("umbraco")
    .controller("AxumUpdateService",
    function ($scope, $http, AxumUpdateService) {
        $scope.getAll = function () {
            $scope.load = true;
            $scope.info = "Retreiving updates";
            AxumUpdateService.getAll($scope.fromDate, $scope.toDate).success(function (data) {
                $scope.result = data;
                $scope.info = data;
                $scope.load = false;
            });
        };
    });
```

AxumUpdateServiceJquery.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

Comment: It looks like an injection error?
Did you inject "umbraco.service" into your main "umbraco" module?

Comment: All of the AngularJS stuff is correct. It is the JQuery stuff that I have added recently that has caused the application to fail so the issue is not with the Angular side of things

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure it's the exact same error I've had but what worked for me was to incrementing the clientDependency version in ClientDependency.config to force it to refresh the cached js files.

Maybe not "proper procedure", but it did the trick for me.